# angular create input component reusable

Tags: angular, validation, input, angular-reactive-forms, reusability

I am creating a reusable text component with validator

```
export class CompInputComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() controlFormGroup: FormGroup;
  @Input() controlLabel: string;
  @Input() controlPlaceHolder: string;
  @Input() controlName: string;
  @Input() errorMessage: string;
  private _isRequired = false;

  @Input()
  get isRequired(): boolean {
    return this._isRequired;
  }
  set isRequired(val: boolean) {
    this._isRequired = coerceBooleanProperty(val);
  }

  @Output() onComponentReady: EventEmitter<FormGroup> = new EventEmitter<FormGroup>();
  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.isRequired);
    if(this.isRequired){
      console.log(this.isRequired);

      this.controlFormGroup.addControl(this.controlName, new FormControl('', Validators.required));
    }else{
      this.controlFormGroup.addControl(this.controlName, new FormControl(''));
    }

    this.onComponentReady.emit(this.controlFormGroup);
  }
}

<div [formGroup]="controlFormGroup">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>{{controlLabel}}</mat-label>
        <input matInput [placeholder]="controlPlaceHolder" [formControlName]="controlName" />
        <mat-error *ngIf="controlFormGroup.controls.controlName.hasError('required')">">
            <span [innerHTML]="errorMessage"></span>
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

My problem is that I can’t set up the mat-error. I have the following error:

core.js:5967 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined
at CompInputComponent_Template

The name of the control is not hard but also dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, you are creating your form controls dynamically, it means they doesn't exist at the beginning. you need to check if the form control created.

```
   export class CompInputComponent implements OnInit{
      @Input() controlFormGroup: FormGroup;
      @Input() controlLabel: string;
      @Input() controlPlaceHolder: string;
      @Input() controlName: string;
      @Input() errorMessage: string;
      private _isRequired = false;
    
      @Input()
      get isRequired(): boolean {
        return this._isRequired;
      }
      set isRequired(val: boolean) {
        this._isRequired = coerceBooleanProperty(val);
      }
    
      @Output() onComponentReady: EventEmitter<FormGroup> = new EventEmitter<FormGroup>();
      
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
      
      ngOnInit(){
        console.log(this.isRequired);
        if(this.isRequired){
          console.log(this.isRequired);
    
          this.controlFormGroup.addControl(this.controlName, new FormControl('', Validators.required));
        }else{
          this.controlFormGroup.addControl(this.controlName, new FormControl(''));
        }
    
        this.onComponentReady.emit(this.controlFormGroup);
      }
    }
    
    <div [formGroup]="controlFormGroup">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>{{controlLabel}}</mat-label>
            <input matInput [placeholder]="controlPlaceHolder" [formControlName]="controlName" />
            <mat-error *ngIf="!!controlFormGroup.controls.controlName && controlFormGroup.controls.controlName.hasError('required')">">
                <span [innerHTML]="errorMessage"></span>
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Comment: This compiles but when my input is invalid at the time of sending the message does not display in mat-error

Comment: well it seams controls of controlFormGroup is missing.  be sure if the control name exist.
and try this way.
*ngIf="controlFormGroup.controls[controlName].errors

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly when I click on the field and then I go out